# Re-Call appdelegate applicationdidfinishload

Tags: ios, objective-c

Inside my code, there's a place that I want to recall the `applicationdidfinishload` function, it's like restarting the app, a workaround since apple wouldn't like it if the app restarts.
But I fail to do it no matter what I try… Is there any way to do so? just reload the app by calling that function... but how to call it?  I tried several methods from the internet but no luck...
I just want from within the app, in another view controller, if a certain condition I have is fulfilled, to reload the `applicationDidFinishLoading` from the app delegate.

Comment: You can't and should not do that. Move all the codes in the applicationDidFinishLoading to a separate method and call it directly.

Comment: This is not a possible. give the reasons why you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

That method is not responsible for loading the app. The system loads your app (using `UIApplicationMain`) and tells you when the app has been loaded using that delegate method, so that you can prepare for the app's normal execution (such as setting shared resources, UI elements, appearance, etc.).

`UIApplicationMain` will never return, under normal circumstances, thus you will not be allowed to restart the application.

If you want to restart your interface orientation, one easy solution is to throw away the `UIWindow` object and create a new one. **Note, that this is a terrible user experience!**

If you have come to an unspeakable situation where you are no longer able to continue executing the app (you should not get to such situations but the worst of cases), you should notify the user that he should kill the app from task manager and restart it themselves.